# Values increase without reason

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, boolean, logic

I get values coming from sensors. Thes are the boundaries:

I only have to use Boolean variables and if else statements. Others loops I have tried but in Real time Data coming from sensors it don't work like that.

So the problem is:

I get values from stream

> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.5
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.5
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9
> 3.9

Above stream comes many times.
I need to do `b++` when I get this streams once.

```
var count1 = 0
var count2 = 0

var countValue1 = true
var countValue2 = false

if (x1 == 3.9) {
    if (countValue1) {
        count1++
        count2 = 0

        if (count1 == 22) {
            count1 = 0
            b++
            // if(x1 < 3.5 )
            countValue1 = false
            countValue2 = true
        }
    } else if (countValue2) {
        count2++
        count1 = 0
        if (count2 == 22) {
            count2 = 0
            b++
            countValue1 = true
            countValue2 = false
        }
    }
}
```

In First Event it works fine.
The second times I run the app my b value increase by 4 or 3 sometimes. I don't know why this happen.

Comment: Are you supposed to be checking for ``x == 3.5`` as well? Right now it just increments ``b`` for every 22 values of ``3.9`` you see. You're switching between ``count1`` and ``count2`` but that doesn't seem to make any difference? You're doing the same thing whichever one you're counting

Comment: Also, it's not usually a good idea to check floating-point values for equality.  (A decimal fraction like 3.9 can't be represented exactly in binary floating-point; you may get a value which is close enough to be _displayed_ as 3.9, but not actually equal it.)  If you need an exact decimal value, a type like BigDecimal would be more suitable; otherwise, you're better off checking for a range, e.g. `if (x1 in 3.85..3.95)`.

Comment: I tried your if(3.85..3.95) but issue not resolved.  Could you tell me that anywhere my values will get stuck or stored in this logic ? .it would be helpful.